# Test subscription to EventAggregator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, eventaggregator

Thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694195/moq-event-aggregator-is-it-possible) I've managed to test publish event of PRISM EventAggregator (faking with FakeItEasy)

```
[TestCase]
public void test_that_publish_occured()
{
    var fakeEventAg = A.Fake<IEventAggregator>();
    var fakeEvent = A.Fake<MyEvent>();

    A.CallTo(() => fakeEventAg.GetEvent<MyEvent>())
      .Returns(fakeEvent);

    MyViewModel mvm = new MyViewModel(fakeEventAg);

    mvm.ICommandThatCausesPublishToBeCalled.Execute();

    A.CallTo(() => fakeEvent.Publish(A<SomeClass>.Ignored))
      .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

But I have failed to test subscribe to this event. I have tried the following but I get an exception "Non virtual methods can not be intercepted".

```
[TestCase]
public void test_that_event_is_listened()
{
    var fakeEventAg = A.Fake<IEventAggregator>();
    var fakeEvent = A.Fake<MyEvent>();
    A.CallTo(() => fakeEventAg.GetEvent<MyEvent>())
      .Returns(fakeEvent);

    // subscription occurs in the constructor
    MyViewModel2 mvm2 = new MyViewModel2(fakeEventAg);

    A.CallTo(() => fakeEventAg.GetEvent<MyEvent>()
      .Subscribe(A<Action<PayloadClass>>.Ignored))
      .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

How can I test that a subscription to an event has occurred? It doesn't have to be unit test, but can also be integration test.

Comment: The error is happening because the `Subscribe` method is not virtual and therefore can't be mocked. I see that the `EventBase` class (which `MyEvent` is based on) has a `Subscriptions` property. Perhaps you could examine that collection to verify that your event has been added?

Comment: yes, the Subscriptions property works if I use real EventAggregator. With a faked EA it remains 0. But I can do the test also with real EA, so it solves my problem. Thanks! If you formulate your comment into an answer, then I can also mark it as selected answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because the `Subscribe` method is not virtual and therefore can't be mocked. I see that the `EventBase` class (which `MyEvent` is based on) has a `Subscriptions` property. You should be able to examine that collection to verify that your event has been added.

Comment: of course I had to use reflection to get the Subscriptions property, but I guess that's ok in a test...

Comment: What class is your event actually derived from? I was assuming that it was something like `CompositePresentationEvent`. The `EventBase` class doesn't actually implement a `Subscribe` method, but the derived classes do. If you are actually implementing the `Subscribe` method, you could change it to be virtual just for the sake of mocking. Alternatively, the `EventBase` class has a protected virtual `InternalSubscribe` method that may be mockable (don't know if Moq does protected methods but I would assume that it does).

Comment: `MyEvent` derives from `PubSubEvent`, which in turn derives from `EventBase`. I don't implement `Subscribe` myself, but rely on PRISM. Overriding `Subscribe` would defenitely be an option, but in this case it was better to use reflection to get `Subscriptions`.